# How to work out total headcount per Month and Year using two date columns?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table called Staff_Starters (https://www.dropbox.com/s/khowqfgytc6fvq8/data.csv?dl=0) which is connected to a Date dimension.

Is it possible to create a calculated column or measure in Staff_Starters which counts everyone that has a DateEmployed & stops counting going forward when it has a Termination_Date.

The formula would count individual multiple time until their end date is not equal to current date.

I currently have a table called Staff_Starterts with the main columns:

1. StaffID
2. FullName
3. DateEmployed
4. Termination_Date
5. Team Member
6. Status
7. Practice
8. Region
9. Cluster
10. Level

[Starters, Leavers & Nett][1]

The formula used: Headcount Movement = CALCULATE(
  COUNTROWS(Staff),
  FILTER(Staff,
  AND(Staff[Date Employed]<=MIN(Date_Dim[Calendar_Date]),
      Staff[Termination_Date]>=MAX(Date_Dim[Calendar_Date]))))

Answer (score 2):

```
Count = CALCULATE(                                   
  COUNTROWS(data),
  FILTER(data, 
      AND(data[Date Employed]<MIN('Calendar'[Date]),
          data[TerminationDate]>MAX('Calendar'[Date])
      )
  )
)
```

Results in

```
Date        Count
2017-01-01  85
2017-02-01  74
2017-03-01  58
2017-04-01  37
```

---

**Edit**: In response to a comment, explanation follows. (quotes from msdn)

`CALCULATE`:

> Evaluates an expression in a context that is modified by the specified filters

`COUNTROWS`: (obvious, but keeping for completeness)

> counts the number of rows in the specified table, or in a table defined by an expression

`FILTER`:

> Returns a table that represents a subset of another table or expression.

`AND`:

> Checks whether both arguments are TRUE.

---

```
AND(data[Date Employed]<MIN('Calendar'[Date]),
```

Includes only entries with `Date Employed` before the start of current selected period.

```
    data[TerminationDate]>MAX('Calendar'[Date])
```

Includes only entries with `TerminationDate` after the end of current selected period.

---

This should be enough to adapt the measure to count "leavers", "starters" and so on, as long as you can define it in terms of comparing start, termination and selected period dates.

Comment: Hi @user5226582

The formula throws me back an error stating A single value for column 'Calendar_Date' in table 'Date_Dim' cannot be determined. This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column that contains many values without specifying an aggregation such as min, max, count, or sum to get a single result.

Comment: Thank you very much @user5226582, it works now. Is it possible to also workout the headcount movement based off that formula where it would count starters, leavers & net growth?

Comment: You're very welcome. This is a different question, though I added some explanation, which should be enough to adapt the measure to what you need.

Comment: I am sorry to say that the formula is not adding up to what my starters & leavers say as it should have a drop in May.